# Finite Hausdorff spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is a finite Hausdorff space necessarily discrete?

Comment: Seems a little harsh to retroactively pile on downvotes on a question that was welcomed in the first days of MO's existence. It was a more innocent time. :-)

Answer (score 17):

Just thought of another answer to this.  Any topology on a finite set is compact.  Any map from a discrete topology is continuous.  Hence by the famous theorem on maps from compact spaces into Hausdorff spaces, the identity map on a finite space is a homeomorphism from the discrete topology to the given Hausdoff topology.

A certain phrase involving sledgehammers and walnuts springs to mind, though.

Comment: LOL, that was funny (I mean about the walnuts...)

Answer (score 14):

Yes.  Better, it works for $T_1$, too: $T_1$ is the axiom that one-point sets are closed.

Then since the set is finite, the complement of any point is also closed; the point is open.  That's the discrete topology.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Let $X$ be finite and Hausdorff. It is enough to show that every point $x$ in $X$ is open. For every point $y$ different from $x$, there is an open neighborhood $U_{y}$ of $x$ not meeting $y$. The intersection of the $U_{y}$'s is open and equals $\left\{ x\right\}$.